# Why is the following R code failing because of the absence of curly braces after the first if condition?

Tags: r, if-statement, syntax

The following R code is resulting in **"Error: object 'test' not found".**

```
condition <- 1
if(condition == 0)
if(condition == 1)
{
  test <- "Pass"
}
print(test)
```

But if I add a curly braces after the if condition as shown below then it works fine.

```
condition <- 1
if(condition == 0){}
if(condition == 1)
{
  test <- "Pass"
}
print(test)
```

I googled the structure of **if condition** in R and found [this page](https://www.nbshare.io/notebook/560506415/If-Else-Statement-In-R/) where it is written that curly braces are optional. Then why is the code failing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> where it is written that curly braces are optional

*Curly braces* are optional. But there needs to be *some* expression after an `if`. So R takes the next expression that it finds, which happens to be the entire subsequent `if` expression. So your first code is parsed as if you had written

```
condition <- 1
if(condition == 0) {
    if(condition == 1)
    {
      test <- "Pass"
    }
}
print(test)
```

Anyway, the page you found is a poor quality resource and I recommend you forget about it; in fact, about optional curly braces here is what it actually says:

> Note curly brackets are optional, if not followed by else condition in R.

And **this is false**. The presence or absence of an `else` (note: there’s no such thing as an “else condition”!) is completely irrelevant for whether braces are optional. The rest of the page is of similar poor quality.

Answer (score 1):

For you original code

```
condition <- 1
if(condition == 0)
if(condition == 1)
{
  test <- "Pass"
}
print(test)
```

the first `if` takes the chunk of second `if` as its statement by default, equivalently,

```
condition <- 1
if(condition == 0) {
    if(condition == 1)
    {
       test <- "Pass"
    }
}
print(test)
```

but you never ever enter the inner `if` due to `condition <- 1`, such that the variable `test` is not initialized at all.